# Multiple imputation for count data

Tags: missing-data, count-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, mice

Date,  Transect,    Year,   Species,   Tr.Length,   Month,   numb.on.transect

I am working with historical sea-survey data.... boat transects counting birds on water.
only there are some transects that were not completed so I need to imputate the missing transects to estimate the "num.on.transect"

Dependant variable: num.on transect

predictor variables: Transect, Year, Month

I know I should run a poisson regression to impute the data but I cannot get micemd code to work properly ! anyone know how I would write the code for this?